# Aggregate wrapper

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Handy wrapper for aggregates to use with `emplace*()` container's member functions:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template< typename type >
struct aggregate_wrapper
    : type
{

    aggregate_wrapper() = default;

    template< typename ...arguments,
              bool is_noexcept = noexcept(::new (std::declval< void * >()) type{std::declval< arguments >()...}) >
    constexpr
    aggregate_wrapper(arguments &&... _arguments) noexcept(is_noexcept)
        : type{std::forward< arguments >(_arguments)...}
    { ; }

};

#include <vector>

#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    struct A {};
    struct B {};
    struct S { A & a; B & b; };
    A a; B b;
    std::vector< aggregate_wrapper< S > > v;
    v.emplace_back(a, b);
    S & s = v.back(); // implicitly convertible to S
    assert(&s.a == &a);
    assert(&s.b == &b);
    v.pop_back();
    v.push_back({a, b}); // (implicitly?) copy-constructible
    assert(&v.back().a == &a);
    assert(&v.back().b == &b);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

`aggregate_wrapper< T >` mimics `T` in sense of special functions available (copy/move-constructors/assignment operators and destructor). All public data memebers are available via `operator .` as well.

It is possible to provide incomplete list of public data member initializers to constructor, but in such a case compiler's warning will be here (default data member initializers for omitted data members can solve the problem (C++14 feature)).

[There is](https://github.com/tomilov/variant/blob/master/test/src/versatile.cpp#L9) very comprehensive test for this wrapper.

What are there design flaws (maybe there is issue with `explicit`?)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34836/discussion-on-question-by-orient-aggregate-wrapper).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a revision to your solution. The code is quite self-documenting. So, I don't bother going over it literally. Please comment if you have any questions. Original version of the code can be found [here](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/CPP_Utility/blob/master/cppu/aggregate_wrapper.hpp) with unit test code [here](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/CPP_Utility/blob/master/test/aggregate_wrapper.cpp).

```
/// Wraps aggregates and provides a variadic forwarding constructor.
/// Enables in-place construction. Value initializes the aggregate
/// when default constructed.
template <typename T>
class aggregate_wrapper : public T {
private:
  using base = T;

public:
  using aggregate_type = T;

  // no `explicit`; aggregate initialization can be done implicitly;
  // be consistent with that
  template <typename... Ts>
  aggregate_wrapper(Ts&&... xs)
      : base{std::forward<Ts>(xs)...} {
    // nop
  }
};

template <typename T, std::size_t n>
class aggregate_wrapper<T[n]> {
private:
  using array = T[n];

public:
  using aggregate_type = T[n];

  template <typename... Ts>
  aggregate_wrapper(Ts&&... xs)
      : arr_{std::forward<Ts>(xs)...} {
    // nop
  }
  aggregate_wrapper(const array& arr) {
    std::copy(arr, arr + n, arr_);
  }
  aggregate_wrapper(array&& arr) {
    std::move(arr, arr + n, arr_);
  }

  operator T* () {
    return arr_;
  }
  operator const T* () const {
    return arr_;
  }

private:
  array arr_;
};

// you won't want to use `std::decay_t`;
// consider the case when `T` is an array type
template <typename T>
aggregate_wrapper<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>
wrap_aggregate(T&& x) {
  return std::forward<T>(x);
}
```

I once wanted to write

```
template <typename T,
          typename = std::eanble_if_t<std::is_aggregate<T>::value>>
aggregate_wrapper<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>
wrap(T&& x) {
  return std::forward<T>(x);
}
```

Alas, I don't know how to implement this `std::is_aggregate` thing (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34994364/1348273)).

I have a feeling that you will like [this](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/CPP_Utility). Hope you could join the party and play together ;-]

Comment: What about type traits?

Comment: @Orient `<type_traits>` doesn't help :(

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c62c467acf097653 I mean this shortcoming.

Comment: @Orient `W<A> v;` won't compile. Is this a bug of the standard library implementation or what? I'm confused. Also, you are not supposed to pass non-aggregate types to `T`.

Comment: You defenitely need enabler (in forwarding constructor declaration) to forward properties of base class' constructors. In C++11 it is possible to propagate `noexcept` specifier using `noexcept` operator. Why do you ignore all I wrote?

Comment: @Orien Well, basically, I don't know much about the `noexcept` stuff. Sorry :( Also, I posted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35000324/1348273).

Comment: If expression into operator `noexcept` is not well-formed for a parameters, then constructor for such parameters does not participate in overload resolution. If there no implicitly defined suitable constructors, then type trait results in false for the parameters.

Comment: @Orient It would be nice to add a `size()` method to the array specialization.

Comment: I agree, but my wrapper is just for use within my variant class only.